# Restricting single Rating on each Book by each User : Django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

> **Edited Title** : Limit multiple "Many to One" fields into "One to One" association : Django

We've *Book*, *User* and *Rating* as Django model.

- **Each** *Book* has **many** *Ratings*
- **Each** *Rating* has **one** *Book*
- **Each** *User* has **many** *Ratings*
- **Each** *Rating* has **one** *User*

### For Book

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

### For Book Rating

```
class BookRating(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 6)])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.rating
```

### Problem Statement

How can I ensure that *each User has **atmost** one rating on each book*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do

```
class BookRating(models.Model):
    book = models.ForeignKey(Book, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    rating = models.SmallIntegerField(choices=[(i, i) for i in range(1, 6)], default=1)

    class meta:
        unique_together = ('book','user')
```

Your models do implement a many to many relationship, however you are not getting full access to the django ManyToMany functionality. I recommend you do something like this:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    isbn = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    ratings = models.ManyToManyField(User,through='BookRating')
```

When you do this your BookRating can remain unchanged, but the small change to the Book model gives you full access to the api described here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

What's interesting is that modifying the Book model as described above does not make any changes to your table structures in your database. They remain unchanged. It's simply a matter of unlocking the api.

Comment: Does this situation have a particular name? (As a novice, I encountered it for the first time)

Comment: yes, many to many with through model. I feel this is an area when the django documentation is lacking. I feel the sample code they have should include this unique relationship

Comment: Can you please elaborate the second part of the code (which uses *through*)? I would like to know the structure of **BookRating** in this scenario.

Comment: **Update** : The first solution has solved the problem.

Comment: Glad to know. All the best with your project